# Dynamically address QLineEdit in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a form which contains several QLineEdit elements and a MySQL table where the column names are the same as the names of the corresponding QLineEdit element. 
I have created a list containing all the QLineEdit element names:

```
list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

I stored the data from the MySQL table in a dictionary:

```
dict = {'name1': 'some name', 'name2': 'another name', 'name3': 'one more name'}
```

Now I would like to use a for-loop to fill all the QLineEdit elements. Something like

```
for item in list:
    self.ui.item.setText(dict[item])
```

Obviously, this won't work that way because 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'item'.

Can anybody tell me, if there is a way to do this.

Comment: The simplest method would be to store references to your `QLineEdit` instances in a list and use `zip` or something like that to iterate the list of line edits and the list of elements to set at once.

Comment: `getattr(self.ui, item).setText(dict[item])`

Comment: @Torsten, `dict` is a *type* in Python (a reserved word), don't use it like a variable and same goes for `list`

Comment: @Morwenn, Thanks, storing object references in a list works as well, but is more complex than the getattr trick.

Comment: @qurban, Thanks, I know. The above code isn't the code I used in my script. It was just an example to show the problem.